# Facebook like button stopped working on my wordpress site

Tags: facebook, wordpress, url, facebook-like

Since 2 weeks ago it worked, and still works for old urls. but now for every new post the like button remain at zero, and if i press the button it **blinks 1** but go back to zero immediately.

**My site:** http://arielmartini.com/

**An old url that (still) works:**  http://arielmartini.com/2011-06-30-bixiga70

**A new url that no longer works:** http://arielmartini.com/2011-07-02-romulo

Even if I put the url [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) it doesn't work (try with the 2 url above - "URL to Like" field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i didn't had [open graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) on my page. Using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-revised-open-graph-meta-tag/) fixed it. You can also analyse the page using [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're using **both** the old Facebook "Share" and the newer Facebook "Like" buttons.  However Facebook Share (via static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/ is the old SDK and is being deprecated).

You'll just want to use the new SDK (which you are correctly including) at http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js.

I believe removing the conflicting "share" button will solve your problem.

Comment: hi, thanks for the insight. i removed fbconnect plugin and share button but still can't like the page.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the url you posted, there is a javascript console error (see image) which is causing the javascript code from continuing execution.

[image: facebook javascript error]

**To fix it**, remove this line of code from your wordpress site, or disable the plugin that is adding this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://arielmartini.com/wp-content/plugins/fbconnect/fbconnect.js?pluginver=99&#038;ver=3.1.4'></script>
```

You can't load both the deprecated fbconnect.js file as well as the new Facebook javascript sdk .js file that you load on line 435. If anything is relying on the old deprecated library, I would suggest upgrade as soon as possible because Facebook is killing deprecated functionality all the time.

Comment: hi, thanks for the insight. i removed fbconnect plugin and share button but still can't like the page.

Comment: I just clicked both like buttons on http://arielmartini.com/2011-07-02-romulo and both worked for me (chrome/win7). what browser were you using?

Comment: well, oddly enough the romulo started working fine. but for the last post (danilo) it dont work yet. i tried other browsers. maybe it's just a facebook bug :/